# Is madpay(google pay and apple pay) working in Russia?

Tags: flutter, payment, subscription

I need to integrate payment system Sberbank in current project and, in order to achieve that, in sdk says i should use madpay(https://pub.dev/packages/mad_pay)

Answer (score -1):

According to *The Wall Street Journal*

> Apple is removing Mir cards as an option in Apple Pay, Mir’s operator said Friday. Mir is run by the National Payment Card System, known by its Russian initials NSPK. It is owned by Russia’s central bank.

> “Google Pay is pausing payments-related services in Russia as a result of payment services disruption out of our control,” a Google spokeswoman said.

So, both Google Pay and Apple Pay are currently paused in Russia

Ref: [https://www.wsj.com/livecoverage/russia-ukraine-latest-news-2022-03-25/card/apple-google-cut-ties-to-russia-s-mir-payment-cards-7VvpuBFxa2roLf1KhwQH#:~:text=%E2%80%9CGoogle%20Pay%20is%20pausing%20payments,%2C%E2%80%9D%20a%20Google%20spokeswoman%20said](https://www.wsj.com/livecoverage/russia-ukraine-latest-news-2022-03-25/card/apple-google-cut-ties-to-russia-s-mir-payment-cards-7VvpuBFxa2roLf1KhwQH#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9CGoogle%20Pay%20is%20pausing%20payments,%2C%E2%80%9D%20a%20Google%20spokeswoman%20said).